# what is the value of Rin? (different problem)

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image]

I calculated voltage at Vx. How to know the input impedance? V- is at virtual gnd. Will it be Ra+(Rb||R1).  My question of input impedance seeing from node Vs is right or should we consider only from node Vx. I’m trying to intuitively understand opamps.

Comment: This is different question than previous one

Comment: Well, I would say that Rin = Ra+(Rb||R1) if we are dealing with an ideal opamp.